# Sitecore Experience Profile DashBoard is Empty

Tags: mongodb, experience-profile

We are facing issue on production enviornment ad issue is that Sitecore Experience Profile DashBoard is Empty and this issue is only on production not on UAT or QA when i scanned through logs i found this error many times.

```
Cannot submit pending item: MongoDB.Driver.MongoQueryException: QueryFailure flag was Executor error: Overflow sort stage buffered data usage of 34089254 bytes exceeds internal limit of 33554432 bytes (response was { "$err" : "Executor error: Overflow sort stage buffered data usage of 34089254 bytes exceeds internal limit of 33554432 bytes", "code" : 17144 }).
   at MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoReplyMessage`1.ReadHeaderFrom(BsonBuffer buffer)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoConnection.ReceiveMessage[TDocument](BsonBinaryReaderSettings readerSettings, IBsonSerializer serializer, IBsonSerializationOptions serializationOptions)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Operations.QueryOperation`1.GetFirstBatch(IConnectionProvider connectionProvider)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Operations.QueryOperation`1.Execute(IConnectionProvider connectionProvider)
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbInteractionStorage.RenumberInteractions(Guid contactId)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbDataAdapterProvider.RenumberInteractions(ID contactId)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.ContactRepository.ReconcileContact(Contact contact, LeaseOwner owner, TimeSpan duration)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.SubmitSessionContext.RenumberInteractions.Process(SubmitSessionContextArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.SubmitSessionContext.SubmitSessionContextPipeline.Run(SubmitSessionContextArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.HttpSessionContextManager.Submit(Session session)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.SubmitQueueService.WakeUp()
```

Can some body suggest me resolution of above issue

Comment: How big is your xDB database? This seems to be related to a limit mongo. It happens when you attemp to sort too many records in memory without an index

Comment: Mongo DB is not muscular enough so we are trying to sort too many records in memory without an index is there a resolution to this issue

Comment: Seems to be part of mongo limitation: "If MongoDB cannot use an index to get documents in the requested sort order, the combined size of all documents in the sort operation, plus a small overhead, must be less than 32 megabytes."(http://www.dba86.com/docs/mongo/3.6/reference/limits.html) . 

Is this custom code?

Comment: My idea is to increase the memory limit by executing following command : db.adminCommand({setParameter: 1, internalQueryExecMaxBlockingSortBytes:50151432}) Any opinions on this

Comment: What query is this though? Something custom?

Comment: We found that Tracker.IsActive= false and it says that Release contact Processor is skipped Can this be reason that Sitecore Experience Profile DashBoard is Empty